# Three way relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

having a brain failure with a relationship between three objects, hoping someone can help me out.

I have four models: `Team`, `User`, `ProjectType` and `Project`

- `Team` has many `User`, has many `ProjectType`
- `User` belongs to many `Team`, has many `ProjectType`
- `ProjectType` belongs to many`User`, belongs to many `Team`, has many `Project`
- `Project` belongs to `ProjectType`

As a single user can belong to many teams, I want to request the `ProjectTypes` that a `User` has access to, but only within the `Team` they are currently logged in with. It may be the case that a `User` has access to project types across multiple teams, but will only be logged in to one team at any time, so I need just that subset.

I'm hoping this structure makes sense, but I'm struggling to get access to the data I want easily

So I'd like to do `$user->projectTypes` and get all project types for that user, but only the subset of the team they're currently logged in with.

Equally, once I've got that, I want to be able to get `$user->projectTypes->projects` within that set.

I'd like to do this whilst maintaining all of the nice relationship methods I get with Laravel, but am struggling to setup the data structure to support this, and get the data in turn.

Worth adding I'm using Laravel 4.2, but am not desparately tied to it, and can upgrade to 5.x if necessary to get this functionality.

Comment: Check out Laravel's query scopes. I have used them for something pretty similar. Instead of working just off of the relationship, you "pre" filtering the results of the $user query to only show those related to the teamId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've [defined the relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many) as you've described, you can access the ProjectTypes that belong to a User, that also belong to a certain Team (in your case `$teamid` should be the id of the Team that the User is currently logged in to) like so:

```
$projectTypes = $user->projectTypes()->where('team_id', $teamid)->get();
```

To easily access a collection of all Projects that belong to **all** ProjectTypes that belong to a User, you would first define [the HasManyThrough relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through) like so:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Project', 'ProjectType');
    }

}
```

Then you can access that collection like so:

```
$projects = $user->projects;
```

And finally, to access the Projects that belong to the ProjectTypes that belong to a User, that also belong to a certain Team (i.e. what it seems you're looking for), you can use [lists()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) to get a list of relevant ProjectType ids, then [whereIn()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) to filter for those within that list:

```
$projectTypeIds = $user->projectTypes()->where('team_id', $teamid)->lists('id');
$projects = $user->projects()->whereIn('projecttype_id', $projectTypeIds)->get();
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted, thanks - I was originally trying to avoid doing any kind of `whereIn()` (avoiding the requirement to do a query beforehand to get that array) but I think for now that's the best solution!

Comment: Glad that helped. Laravel usually executes multiple SQL queries per Eloquent query anyway, so doing the separate Eloquent query to get the array of ids beforehand probably won't have any real downsides in terms of performance versus any other possible solution.